# Express: How to get the `params` from the original URL

Tags: node.js, express, router

I have an endpoint: POST /`:service`/confirm. This is handled by

**index.js**

```
router.use("/:services", services);
```

**services.js**

```
router.post("/confirm", (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.params);
 });
```

I'm planning to get the `params.services` inside of `services.js`. But when I logged it, its empty. I'm assuming that `req.params` is focusing on the current path. Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: are you using any node modules?

Answer (score 3):

You need set [`mergeParams`](http://expressjs.com/ru/api.html#express.router) option to true:

> Preserve the req.params values from the parent router. If the parent
>   and the child have conflicting param names, the child’s value take
>   precedence.